# Удалить дублирующиеся записи из БД mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица mySQL `table_1` такая:

```
id | name    | ... | ... |  
1  | vasya   | ... | ... |  
2  | sasha   | ... | ... |  
3  | vasya   | ... | ... |  
4  | gena    | ... | ... |  
5  | sasha   | ... | ... |
```

Надо сделать из неё `table_2`

```
id | name    | ... | ... |  
1  | sasha   | ... | ... |  
2  | vasya   | ... | ... |  
3  | gena    | ... | ... |
```

То бишь, по столбцу `name` найти все совпадения имён, и удалить лишние, оставив только одну, последнюю по id, запись. И записать результат в новую таблицу.

Как это лучше сделать, учитывая, что в `table_1` 100000+ строк, и сколько из них дублируется, неизвестно? Спасибо.

Comment: insert into table_2 select distinct * from table_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> по столбцу name найти все совпадения имён, и удалить лишние, оставив только одну, последнюю по id, запись. И записать результат в новую таблицу.

Разумнее сделать это в обратном порядке.

```
-- записать желаемое в новую таблицу
INSERT INTO table2 (id, name, ...)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, ...
FROM table1 t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t11.id) id, t11.name
       FROM table1 t11
       GROUP BY t11.name
     ) sq ON t1.id=sq.id AND t1.name=sq.name;

-- очистить старую таблицу
TRUNCATE table1;

-- скопировать в неё только нужные записи
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name, ...)
SELECT id, name, ...
FROM table2;
```

Comment: спасибо, что-то получилось, по крайней мере, количество строк уменьшилось втрое)))

Comment: Надеюсь, Вы не стали без проверки результата от выполнения первого запроса сразу выполнять второй и третий запросы?

Comment: стал)) но предварительно сохранил дамп) судя по поиску, дубли удалились, вопрос в том, не удалилось ли ещё чего вместе с дублями? как бы проверить...

Comment: Вы проверьте, то ли удалилось. А то на словах Вы просили оставить максимальные ID, а в примере новые ID вообще взяли с потолка... *как бы проверить* - да очень просто. `SELECT COUNT(*)` по старой таблице даст общее количество записей, а `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name)` - количество записей, которые должны были остаться. Это в штуках. А по персоналиям - проверьте пару групп с одинаковым name, если с ними всё правильно, не вижу оснований, чтобы на других были косяки.